# Android Studio (AS) and Emulator are working fine, but AS is not recognizing the emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I am newbie here and new to the flutter and Android studio as well. I am trying to run sample Flutter App on my virtual device but its not running.
My system Info- Intel core I3 processor, X64 bit operating system, Windows 10 Operating system and 10 GB RAM.
Android Studio and Virtual device are working fine but not connecting with each other. No device is shown in the Android studio.

Error image
[image: Error Image]

SDK image
[image: SDK image]

AVD creation image
[image: AVD creation image]

Comment: Try running  File -> Invalidate catches and restart and please close emulator before doing this

Comment: Does your emulator device show up when you run `flutter devices` command from your terminal?

Comment: @KaranMehta.. just tried, initially showing some improvements but later it failed. the error was- Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install C:\Users\WIN 10\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk: cmd: Failure calling service package: Broken pipe (32)
Error launching application on Android SDK built for x86.

Comment: What's the error now?

Comment: @SiddharthPatankar. I tried this, After File-> invalidate catches /restart and then the the terminal was showing this.... C:\Users\WIN 10\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app>flutter devices
1 connected device:

Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)

Comment: Try launching the app directly from the terminal by running `flutter run` inside the project root directory and check if it works

Comment: Hey @KaranMehta... its working now. I have restarted everything, and now its working.

Comment: I'm adding it as an answer please accept and upvote it if it helped you

Comment: Please upvote it as well because it will help others as well finding answers

Comment: @KaranMehta- It was my first time. That's why, when I am upvoting your answer, the system is reflecting this-------- Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running File -> Invalidate catches and restart

Note : Please close the currently running emulator before running that